# Char Point to Hex Value

Tags: c

I have a pointer to a Char storing the value 'done' in it.

I believe the value in hex for 'done' should be: 656e6f64

However when trying my test code:

```
unsigned int test = (unsigned int) *label;
fprintf(stderr, "  label is %08x \n", mop);
```

It will print out a value like this:

```
00000064
```

Can't really figure out what I am doing wrong, is it shifting? am I casting wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: What is `mop`? I'd post more of your code as there isn't enough here to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: Referencing a pointer to `char` will give you *one* `char`, not the whole array. Easier to have a pointer to `int`, and cast your `char` pointer to that.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths What if the string is longer than sizeof(int)? What if it is shorter?

Comment: @etsy sorry. Mop should be named 'test'

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: It's not, OP tells us so in the question.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, okay. What you suggested should be fine for length 4 strings. But wont it be printed in the reverse order? If the system is using Big endian representation for int?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: It'll be printed in reverse order on a little endian system, not a big endian one. But there's no reason why that's a problem, and the OP is clearly expecting this.

Comment: My bad, the naming convention all seems to confuse me. And yes, OP is expecting that. So fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest alternative I can think of right now is -

```
int i;
for (i = 0; label[i] != '\0'; i++)
    printf("%02x", (int)label[i]);
printf("\n");
```

This should give exactly what you want. Also any representation issues shouldn't come in.